Change name of all attachments in Power Apps
Apologie as I'm quite new to Power Apps.
I've created the form where I have attachments section linked together with Camera control.
I've used the below to dynamically name Photos taken via Camera control to add prefix which is unique reference number typed into DataCardValue14 :
Set( varName, GUID() ); Collect(colCameraImages, { DisplayName: DataCardValue14.Text & " - " & varName & ".jpg", Id: DataCardValue14.Text & " - " & varName & ".jpg", Value: Self.Photo } );
Unfortunately this only works only for photos captured by Camera control but not Attachment control itself( external Camera app).
Is there alternative way such as UpdateIf or Patch ? Similar to the one from this topic text.
Thank you in advance
I've tried to follow both solution from the link in section OnAddFile but did not work at all.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
